# Errors and Exceptions:C2M5L4_Errors_and_Exceptions-V2

Tags: python, random, try-catch, except

```py
import random

participants = ['Jack','Jill','Larry','Tom']

def Guess(participants):
    my_participant_dict = {}
    for participant in participants:
        my_participant_dict[participant] = random.randint(1, 9)
    if my_participant_dict['Larry'] == 9:
        return True
    else:
        return False
    
print(Guess(participants))
```

Comment: 1) Code formatting is important.  2) What is your actual question?  I strongly recommend you read the [help section of the site](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for guidance on both how to ask and how to answer questions on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Revised Guess() function
def Guess(participants):
    my_participant_dict = {}
    for participant in participants:
        my_participant_dict[participant] = random.randint(1, 9)
    try:
        if my_participant_dict['Larry'] == 9:
            return True
    except KeyError:
        return None
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Is this your solution, or just an edit to your question?